# Why is VirtualBox slow when unfocused in macOS?

Tags: mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance, power

I am on a Mac laptop (MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) i7 / 32GB RAM) running Win10 in VirtualBox. I have noticed a degradation in performance of the VM when the VirtualBox VM window is not the focused window on the Mac. To be clear, this happens when I switch to another desktop, not just when the screen times-out, etc.

The slowdown doesn't happen immediately; it seems to be a gradual thing. The longer the VM window is not the focused window, the slower the VM will run. Network calls will begin to fail in Windows. Keyboard and mouse events will miss or replay too many times. Switching back to the VM window will immediately boost it back to normal.

This is primarily annoying because I generally access the VM via RDP from another machine. So, I have to keep babying the mac, keeping the machine next to me, keeping the VM fullscreen, moving the mouse around periodically. As long as I do this, everything works fine.

I am guessing this is some sort of power-saving feature on the mac; although, it happens even when plugged in. The VM has 4GB RAM. Closing other processes on the mac does not help, so I don't believe the mac is running out of resources.

How do I get the mac to respect that the app is currently in-use, even though it doesn't think so, or how do I get it to run full blast at all times?

Comment: This is likely to be VB itself. I run Windows 24/7 backgrounded on an old Mac Pro with zero issues… on Parallels. VMWare Fusion is free for personal use, maybe try that if you don’t want to spend on Parallels.

Comment: Did you install Virtual Box Guest Extensions in the Guest Machine?  Try that and see.

Comment: @John guest extensions are installed

Comment: Did the VM speed up?

Comment: I meant they were always installed from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Moving all apps to the same virtual desktop (and nothing full screen) seems to alleviate the symptoms; not ideal, but better. I'll wait to see if there are any other ideas.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue, after a bit of experimenting I found out that running the VM in headless mode fixes this issue. I suppose because in this mode there is never going to be a concept of focusing the VM window, hence it runs at full speed all the time.

[image]